# if statement read only one condition angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

[image]

```
case Role.PARENT: { 
    if (this.user.profile == null) { 
        this.router.navigate([`/profil-parent`]); 
        console.log('here into profil parent'); 
    } else { 
        this.router.navigate([`/dashboard`]); 
        console.log('here into dashboard'); 
    } 
    break; 
} 
case Role.ENSEIGNANT: { 
    break; 
}
```

I have an if statement, in case the user has no profile. I want him to navigate to a special page. If he has a profile, I want him to navigate to the dashboard. But the if statement works only on one condition, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: case Role.PARENT: {
                if (this.user.profile == null) {
                  this.router.navigate([`/profil-parent`]);
                  console.log('here into profil parent');                  
                }
                else {
                  this.router.navigate([`/dashboard`]);
                  console.log('here into dashboard');

                }
                break;
              }
              case Role.ENSEIGNANT: {
                break;
              }

Comment: What do you get if you have `console.log(this.user);` ?

Comment: Remove the `{` `}` in the "case", The instruction case is: `case:...instructions... break` and check this.user.profile (in general for undefined or null or 0 it's would prefer the way `if (!this.user.profile)`

Comment: Maybe the value is undefined instead of null. In what condition is the if statement working?